# How to Get string text from multi line EditText

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using an edittext to get user's input. After input user click on option menu button to submit. After submit if the user input is empty it should show an Alert Dialog which is working fine. But even when user have entered some text into text field it still showing empty input.

> XML

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/post_summary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Share a photo, video or idea"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="10"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:minLines="2"
                android:background="#1AFFFFFF"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@color/black" />
```

> Java

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_post);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("New Post");
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });


        data = findViewById(R.id.post_summary);
        st_text = data.getText().toString().trim();
}
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.post) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(st_text)){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreatePostActivity.this,R.style.AlertDialog);
                String titleText = "Error \n  ";
                ForegroundColorSpan foregroundColorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                SpannableStringBuilder ssBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(titleText);
                ssBuilder.setSpan(
                        foregroundColorSpan,
                        0,
                        titleText.length(),
                        Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
                );
                builder.setTitle(ssBuilder);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.setMessage("You can't create empty post");
                dialog.show();
                return false;
            }else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreatePostActivity.this,R.style.AlertDialog);
                builder.setTitle("Success");
                builder.setMessage("Your post is successfully created.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move : st_text = data.getText().toString().trim();
 after : int id = item.getItemId();

So ... your code should look like :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
st_text = data.getText().toString().trim();
        if (id == R.id.post) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(st_text)){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreatePostActivity.this,R.style.AlertDialog);
                String titleText = "Error \n  ";
                ForegroundColorSpan foregroundColorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                SpannableStringBuilder ssBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(titleText);
                ssBuilder.setSpan(
                        foregroundColorSpan,
                        0,
                        titleText.length(),
                        Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
                );
                builder.setTitle(ssBuilder);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.setMessage("You can't create empty post");
                dialog.show();
                return false;
            }else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreatePostActivity.this,R.style.AlertDialog);
                builder.setTitle("Success");
                builder.setMessage("Your post is successfully created.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```